# RSA and its Limitations

Tags: rsa, post-quantum-cryptography

How and why do we face a problem when encrypting values of 0 and 1 using the RSA cryptography Algorithm?
Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: How is this question related to post quantum?

Answer (score 2):

RSA encryption is based on modular exponentiation, where the plaintext $m$ is transformed into a ciphertext $c$ by the operation $c = m^e \pmod n$. For any moderately large value of $e$ (normally 65537), this works OK.

However, the numbers 0 and 1 are unaffected by this operation, because $0^e = 0$ and $1^e = 1$ for any encryption key $e$ and any modulus $n$. Thus in "textbook" RSA, if $m$ is equal to 0 or 1, then $c$ is equal to $m$ and the encryption has no effect.

In practice, this isn't a problem because in the real world, [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Padding) is used to ensure that there is no possibility of $m$ being equal to 0 or 1. Padding can also provide other benefits such as [semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security).